# NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null

Tags: selenium, junit, automated-tests, webdriver, testng

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-NLBMRCD', ip: '192.168.1.15', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_301'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

i have getDriver;

```
public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
```

i have instantiate;

```
public WebDriver instantiate(String strategy) {
        DriverStrategy driverStrategy = DriverStrategyImplementer.chooseStrategy(strategy);
        driver = driverStrategy.setStrategy();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        return driver;
    }
```

i have get instance;

```
public static DriverSingleton getInstance(String driver) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DriverSingleton(driver);
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

config properties;

```
public class ConfigurationProperties {
    @Value("${browser}")
    private String browser;

    public String getBrowser() {
        return browser;
    }

    public void setBrowser(String browser) {
        this.browser = browser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something is going wrong when you create the new driver... Possibly because you're not doing so directly, but are instead using the `DriverStrategy` class.  Can you share the implementation of that class with us?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly due to older *`java.version: '1.8.0_301'`*

Ensure that *JDK* is upgraded to current level of [JDK 8u311](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html).

Comment: i tried but it didn't work